# Yiibootstrap error

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I've installed the Yii bootstrap extension for a Yii project I am working on. When I try to register the bootstrap files I get an error.

This is the code provided:

```
<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>
```

The error I get is as following:

[image]

I hope someone can help me out, I have no idea where to look for.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be using:

`<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>`

instead of

`<?php Yii:app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>`

Note the double colon `::`

Comment: Oops, my bad. I was using the double colon. I've edited my post.

Comment: That would be the weirdest thing, you don't have another class called `Yii` do you?

Comment: I found it! I misscalled the bootstrap class in the configuration. Thanks for you help, if it werent for you I wouldn't have checked the components area.